# Filtering IQueryable sub list

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, filtering

Working with Entity Framework, but that's probably irrelevant 
If I have an Iqueryable, how do I filter a sub list and keep it IQueryable so it doesn't yet hit the DB?

If I have 10 items and each has 3 sub items, how do I filter it so there's a return of all 10 items and their subitems are filtered to where id = 1?

class Item has about 20 properties on it, so I wouldn't want to use projection on each of them, because of maintenance concerns..

```
items = items.select(??);//how to do this so items are returned, and their children are filtered?

class SubItem
{ private int ID { get; set; }
}
class Item 
{
private List<SubItem> SubItems { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just include a where clause when you issue your query?

Comment: good question. The reason is I'm looking to unit test my filters with fake data, rather relying on the DB which will change state over time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I interpret your question as you want to return all `Items` no matter what, but you want to filter `SubItems`.  There is no good way to say "I want to return this object except I want a modified version of X property" for an `IQueryable`. You'll have to use a select statement where you select a new object if you want to this.

Option 1: Return the data separately

```
var itemsAndSubItems = items
    .Select(item => new 
        {
            Item = item,
            SubItems = item.SubItems.Where(sub => sub.ID = 1)
        }
    );
```

or if you don't mind eagerly loading the items into memory:

```
IEnumerable<Item> = items
    .Select(item => new 
        {
            Item = item,
            SubItems = item.SubItems.Where(sub => sub.ID = 1)
        }
    )
    .ToList()
    .Select(row => 
        { 
            var item = row.Item;
            item.SubItems = row.SubItems;
            return item;
        }
    );
```

Option 2: Return a new instance of your class (which it seems you don't want to do)

```
IQueryable<Item> items = items
    .Select(item => new Item 
        { 
            SubItems = item.SubItems.Where(sub => sub.ID == 1),
            OtherProp = item.OtherProp
            /*etc for the other properties on Item*/
        }
    );
```

Option 3: Add another property to your class. I recommend this least. Note that your query will still return all sub items here when you access SubItemsWithIdOne

```
class Item 
{
    private List<SubItem> SubItems { get; set; }
    private List<SubItem> SubItemsWithIdOne 
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.SubItems.Where(sub => sub.ID == 1); 
        }
    }
}
```

Option 4: Add a property on `SubItem` that references it's parent `Item`.  Then return a list of `SubItem`.  This way you'll have both `SubItems` and `Items` where your criteria is satisfied.

...If you're working with an `IEnumerable` you can do:

```
IEnumerable items = items
    .Select(item =>
        {
            item.SubItems.Where(sub => sub.ID = 1);
            return item;
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to filter children down to where there's only one child per parent, you need to start with children, select their parents, and do not touch the parents' subitems:

```
IQueryable<SubItem> childItems = context
    .SubItems.Include("Item")
    .Where(si => si.Id == 1 && si.Item.SomeAttr == someValue);
//               ^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                   |                         |
//                   |           Set a condition on the parent
//  Set a condition on the child
```

I assume that each sub-item has a link "pointing" back at its parent.

Answer (score 1):

```
items.Where(i => i.SubItems.Any(subItem => subItem.Id == 1));
```

Comment: did not work for me ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking is SelectMany. As an example for your case is something like this:

```
  positiveItems = items.SelectMany(x => x.SubItem).Where(x=> x.ID == 1).Select(x=>x.Item);
  //items still IQueryable , so we can concat it with another IQueryable

  negativeItems = items.SelectMany(x=>x.SubItem).Where(x=>x.ID != 1).Select(x=>x.Item);


  //just an using option
  allItems = positiveItems.Concat(negativeItems);
```

And just a suggestion. For high number of reference object set, you can use [ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) It is very simple and fast. I used it couple of production projects and it saved my tons of times.