# Filter IEnumerable Collection using Linq on ASP.NET Web API 2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I need to filter my data based on a Boolean condition using Linq on ASP.NET Web Api 2 C#. But my JSON data returns null when I try filtering the data.

The data is a List of Invites, I want to filter the results based on a MemberID and if the user is attending(IsAttending)

**Here is the Member Model**

```
public class Member
{
    public int MemberID { get; set; }
    public string MemberName { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
    public bool IsAttending { get; set; }
    public int MemberNumber { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public int InviteID { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Invite Iinvite { get; set; }
}
```

**InviteModel**

```
public class Invite
{
    public int InviteID { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string DateTime { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Member> Members { get; set; }
}
```

**Original JSON data without filtering**

```
[{
    "InviteID": 1,
    "Subject": "Hell",
    "DateTime": "March 2017",
    "Members": [{
        "MemberID": 1,
        "MemberName": "roger",
        "IsAdmin": false,
        "IsAttending": false,
        "MemberNumber": 0,
        "PhoneNumber": null,
        "InviteID": 1
    },
    {
        "MemberID": 2,
        "MemberName": "nkosi",
        "IsAdmin": false,
        "IsAttending": false,
        "MemberNumber": 0,
        "PhoneNumber": null,
        "InviteID": 1
    },
    {
        "MemberID": 3,
        "MemberName": "Mphile",
        "IsAdmin": false,
        "IsAttending": false,
        "MemberNumber": 0,
        "PhoneNumber": null,
        "InviteID": 1
    }]
},
{
    "InviteID": 2,
    "Subject": "Hell",
    "DateTime": "March 2018",
    "Members": [{
        "MemberID": 4,
        "MemberName": "roger",
        "IsAdmin": false,
        "IsAttending": false,
        "MemberNumber": 0,
        "PhoneNumber": null,
        "InviteID": 2
    },
    {
        "MemberID": 5,
        "MemberName": "nkosi",
        "IsAdmin": false,
        "IsAttending": false,
        "MemberNumber": 0,
        "PhoneNumber": null,
        "InviteID": 2
    },
    {
        "MemberID": 6,
        "MemberName": "Mphile",
        "IsAdmin": false,
        "IsAttending": false,
        "MemberNumber": 0,
        "PhoneNumber": null,
        "InviteID": 2
    }]
},
{
    "InviteID": 3,
    "Subject": "Hell",
    "DateTime": "Marchs 2017",
    "Members": [{
        "MemberID": 7,
        "MemberName": "Roger Nkosi",
        "IsAdmin": false,
        "IsAttending": true,
        "MemberNumber": 0,
        "PhoneNumber": null,
        "InviteID": 3
    },
    {
        "MemberID": 8,
        "MemberName": "nkosi",
        "IsAdmin": false,
        "IsAttending": false,
        "MemberNumber": 0,
        "PhoneNumber": null,
        "InviteID": 3
    },
    {
        "MemberID": 9,
        "MemberName": "Mphile",
        "IsAdmin": false,
        "IsAttending": false,
        "MemberNumber": 0,
        "PhoneNumber": null,
        "InviteID": 3
    }]
},
{
    "InviteID": 4,
    "Subject": "Hell",
    "DateTime": "Marchs 2017",
    "Members": [{
        "MemberID": 10,
        "MemberName": "Roger Nkosi",
        "IsAdmin": false,
        "IsAttending": true,
        "MemberNumber": 0,
        "PhoneNumber": null,
        "InviteID": 4
    },
    {
        "MemberID": 11,
        "MemberName": "nkosi",
        "IsAdmin": false,
        "IsAttending": true,
        "MemberNumber": 0,
        "PhoneNumber": null,
        "InviteID": 4
    },
    {
        "MemberID": 12,
        "MemberName": "Mphile",
        "IsAdmin": false,
        "IsAttending": true,
        "MemberNumber": 0,
        "PhoneNumber": null,
        "InviteID": 4
    }]
}]
```

**Here is how I filter and return the data**

```
return db.invites.Include("members").ToList()
                .Where(x => x.Members == db.members
                                .Where(xx => xx.IsAttending == true && xx.MemberID == 4)).ToList();
```

Comment: What is your expected result? Your LINQ query will never return any result because you are comparing collections by reference. Please add to your question an example of what will the Json look like after the filtering.

Comment: How can I put this? I want my JSON to be the same, but include members where the member id matches and the IsAttending == true

Comment: What happens if there are members with `IsAttending` both true and false for a specific invite? It's not clear how deep you want your result to be filtered, that's why I asked you to add your expected result inside the question.

Comment: If the member attribute IsAttending == false, that member wont be part of the return JSON data.

Comment: In the original JSON you never have `IsAttending == true && MemberID == 4`.

Comment: You can't filter like that in a "sub list" in linq. 
Questions : 
do you want to retrieve all invites (even the ones where no member fulfill the filter condition) => with an empty member list ? 

Or only the ones which have at least one member fulfilling the conditions 
 => with a filtered member list ?

Comment: Scrobi I have tested with other MemberID  which is part of the JSON array like IsAttending == true && MemberID == 7

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Thinking about it makes me realise what I want is just maybe impossible. What I want is, the JSON response must only include members which fulfil the condition. if there is not single member that fulfil the condition then that invite is not included altogether on in the response. if there is only one member fulfilling the condition the only that member can be party of the "sublist" Members

Comment: Well, you can't do this with your "models" in one step. Take a look at this question, maybe, which offers a few solutions : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865901/filtering-iqueryable-sub-list You could also filter first as mentionned in Dan's answer, to retrieve only the invites which have at least one member fulfilling the condition (but his answer will give you back all members  fore each returned invite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not impossible, is just not achievable with a single LINQ query to the DB.

Assuming `memberId` contains the id of the member you want to filter on:

```
var invites = db.invites.Include(i => i.Members).Where(i => i.Members.Any(m => m.IsAttending && m.MemberID == memberId)).ToList(); // db query
invites = invites.Select(i =>
    new Invite
    {
        DateTime = i.DateTime,
        InviteID = i.InviteID,
        Subject = i.Subject,
        Members = i.Members.Where(m => m.IsAttending && m.MemberID == memberId).ToList()
    }).ToList(); // this removes other members (in memory)

 return invites;
```

Comment: I would just include Members in the first query, to avoid n+1 requests...

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Linq Any() operator.

It will look something more like

```
return db.invites.Include("members").Where(x => x.Members.Any(xx => xx.IsAttending && xx.MemberID == 4).ToList()
```

By the way, I removed the ToList() after db.invites because that will cause the entire members collection to enumerate.  Not sure how big your database is, but that would eventually be a problem.

Comment: This works, but the way I need the result is, it would return the invite if the `(xx => xx.IsAttending && xx.MemberID == 4)` returns true, but I need the users which  `(xx => xx.IsAttending && xx.MemberID == 4)` == false to not be included in the result.