# EF Core 2.0 Global Filter

Tags: c#

I have 2 entity type "Offerta" and "Creator". In Offerta I have only one property  of type "Creator" and I need to filter this with a global filter based on current user.
The app is multitenancy and working with this, but filtering on the child entity is not working.
Any idea for the applying a global filter on the child entity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering IQueryable sub list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865901/filtering-iqueryable-sub-list)

Comment: The Global Query Filter [Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters#limitations) do state: "Filters cannot contain references to navigation properties"